# Related to C++ and Assembly, what is ebp+8?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, g++, reverse-engineering

I have the following C++ code:

```
#include <tuple>
std::tuple<int, bool> foo()
{
    return std::make_tuple(128, true);
}
int main()
{
    auto result = foo();
}
```

The following is the disassembled version of the `foo()` function:

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
sub     esp, 24
mov     BYTE PTR [ebp-13], 1  // second argument
mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-12], 128 // first argument
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+8] // what is this? why we need this here?
sub     esp, 4
lea     edx, [ebp-13]   
push    edx                   // second
lea     edx, [ebp-12]
push    edx                   // first
push    eax                  // same as "ebp+8", what is this?
call    std::tuple<std::__decay_and_strip<int>::__type, std::__decay_and_strip<bool>::__type> std::make_tuple<int, bool>(int&&, bool&&)
add     esp, 12
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
leave
ret     4
```

As I know `ebp+X` is for access function arguments, but there is nothing like this for `foo`, so why does the compiler use it? 
It seems like it's the first parameter for `std::make_tuple()`.

**EDIT:**

I'm not using optimization, I just want to learn RE.

Part of main in Assembly:

```
lea     eax, [ebp-16]  // loaction of local variable
sub     esp, 12
push    eax           // as hidden argument for foo
call    foo()
add     esp, 12
```

Comment: What optimization level, compiler version, compiler options, and other settings?

Comment: @NickC without any optimization. gcc -m32 c.cpp

Comment: https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2005/fall/cs301/support/x86/index.html

Comment: The info behind the link is pertinent but uses AT&T syntax (as opposed to Intel syntax in the question). For clarity: `[base + index * scale + disp]` in intel syntax is equivalent to `disp(base, index, scale)` in AT&T syntax. In the question, base is ebx and disp is 8, so `[ebx + 8]` refers to the value at the memory location 8 bytes behind the value of the ebx register.

Comment: There is no point in learning how to reverse engineer *unoptimized* code. Focus on optimized code. It has a lot less noise and is actually easier to read.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The calling convention specifies that non-trivial objects are returned through a hidden pointer passed as argument. That's what you are seeing. Technically, your code is implemented like this:

```
std::tuple<int, bool>* foo(std::tuple<int, bool>* result)
{
    *result = std::make_tuple(128, true);
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, bool> result;
    foo(&result);
}
```

Comment: If you looked at how it was invoked, that could have also helped ;) Also, consult the relevant calling convention documentation.

Comment: push    eax;
call    foo();

Comment: Yeah but you'd have to check how `eax` was set, and you'd probably see something like `lea eax, [ebp-x]` which should point you to the fact that it's the address of a local variable in `main`, and that can only be `result` itself of course.